# Show that a submodule of a free $\Bbb{Z}[x]$-module may not be free.

Tags: modules, solution-verification

> Show that a submodule of a free $\Bbb{Z}[x]$-module may not be free.

We can see that $\Bbb{Z}$ is a $\Bbb{Z}[x]$-module. Let $a,b \in \Bbb{Z}$ and $a_1x + a_2x^2 + ... + a_nx^n, b_1x+ b_2x^2 + ... + b_mx^m \in \Bbb{Z}[x]$.

$\bullet$ $(a_1x + a_2x^2 + ... + a_nx^n)(a+b) = (a_1x + a_2x^2 + ... + a_nx^n)a + (a_1x + a_2x^2 + ... + a_nx^n)b$

$\bullet$ $(a_1x + a_2x^2 + ... + a_nx^n + b_1x+ ... + b_mx^m)(a) = (a_1x + a_2x^2 + ... + a_nx^n)(a) + (b_1x+ b_2x^2+ ... + b_mx^m)(a)$

$\bullet$ $[(a_1x + a_2x^2 + ... + a_nx^n)(b_1x+ b_2x^2+ ... + b_mx^m)](a) = (a_1x + a_2x^2 + ... + a_nx^n)[(b_1x+ b_2x^2+ ... + b_mx^m)(a)]$

$\bullet$ $1a=a$

This must be free with basis $\{1\}$.

But we know that $\Bbb{Z}_k$ is a submodule of $\Bbb{Z}$ for any $0 \not= k \in \Bbb{N}$. However, no generating set of $\Bbb{Z}_k$ can be linearly independent, since $kz=0$ for all $z \in \Bbb{Z}_k$.

Do you think my answer is correct?

Thanks in advance

Comment: $\mathbb{Z}_k$ isn't a submodule of $\mathbb{Z}$, but a quotient of it.

Comment: As Brad points out, this is the mistake in your proof. Try instead looking at the submodule $(2,x)$.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/388176/prove-2-x-is-not-a-free-r-module

Comment: @AlexYoucis Thank you. So if we look at $(2,x)$, we know that the generating set cannot be $\{2\}$, because there is no way to multiply a polynomial in $\Bbb{Z}[x]$ and get $x$ (because $x/2 \not\in \Bbb{Z}[x]$). The generating set cannot be $\{x\}$ either, since we cannot multiply by $2/x$. So the only possibility is $\{2,x\}$, and we must show that $\{2,x\}$ is linearly independent. However, $4x, -8 \in \Bbb{Z}[x]$ and $(4x)(2) + (-8)(x)=0$. So it cannot be linearly independent, and the submodule cannot be free. Is that right?

Comment: @Artus Basically. Since $(2,x)\subseteq\mathbb{Z}[x]$, if it were free, it would need to be of rank $1$. But, then it would be singly generated, but that's ridiculous. You need to show this last fact, you've just shown that $2$ and $x$ can't generate $(2,x)$ what about something else? In general, the submodules of $R$ are free precisely when $R$ is a PID.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

More generally, let $R$ be a unique factorization domain that is not a principal ideal domain, and let $I$ be a nonprincipal ideal. Then $I$ is a $R$-submodule of the free $R$-submodule $R$, but $I$ itself is not a free $R$-module: any two elements $a\ne b$ of $R$ are $R$-linearly dependent ($ba+(-a)b=0$, with $b\ne0$ or $-a\ne0$), so the only free $R$-submodules of $R$ are cyclic.