# Is $I=(x,y)$ seen as an $\mathbb C[x,y]-$module is free

Tags: modules

Is $I=(x,y)$ seen as an $\mathbb C[x,y]-$module is free ?

I would say that $\{x,y\}$ is a basis but since $x$ and $y$ are in $\mathbb C[x,y]$, may be it's not true.

Comment: $\{x,y\}$ is not a basis, because they satisfy a linear relationship: e.g. $y \cdot x + (-x) \cdot y = 0$.

Comment: @Hurkyl: So how can I conclude ?

Comment: I don't think it's free, otherwise it woul be isomorphic to some $R^n$ (where $R= \Bbb{C}[x,y]$)

Comment: @Crostul: Thank you but how can it be proved ?

Comment: Even though the question is not exactly the same, I think you can find a proof for your question by looking at this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/388176/prove-2-x-is-not-a-free-r-module

Comment: A non principal ideal $I$ of any commutative non-zero ring $R$ cannot be free over $R$, since a basis would have at least two elements ($I$ is not principal), say $a,b \in I$, but then $ab-ba=0$ provides a non trivial $R$-linear dependence relation between $a$ and $b$ ; contradiction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A non principal ideal $I$ of any commutative non-zero ring $R$ cannot be free over $R$, since a basis over $R$ would have at least two elements ($I$ is not principal), say $a,b \in I$, but then $ab-ba=0$ provides a non trivial $R$-linear dependence relation between $a$ and $b$ ; contradiction.

---

Notice that in your case, $(x,y)$ is not even a flat $R$-module, where $R = k[x,y]$ and $k$ is a field, because the morpshim
$M := (x,y) \otimes_R (x,y) \longrightarrow (x,y) \otimes_R R \cong (x,y)$ is not injective (you just have to prove that $x \otimes y - y \otimes x$ is non zero in $M$, because then this element is a non-trivial element of the kernel of this morphism).