# Free submodules of an integral $R.$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals, principal-ideal-domains, integral-domain, free-modules

I was told by the author of the answer here [Showing that the rank of $M$ is exactly $1.$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4823520/showing-that-the-rank-of-m-is-exactly-1/4823533#4823533) that: Free submodules of an integral domain $R$ are exactly the principal ideals of $R.$

I am wondering which theorem, proposition or example in Dummit & Foote, third edition, say this. Could someone clarify this to me please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Submodules of $R$ are precisely the ideals of $R$ (this is by definition of an ideal). Free submodules of $R$ are thus ideals which are isomorphic (as modules) to $R^n$ for some $n$ (the rank of the free module). Say the ideal $I$ is generated freely by $a_1,…,a_n \in R$

We show that if $R$ is integral then $n\leq 1$. Indeed otherwise $a_1$ and $a_2$ are distinct, so the submodules they generate inside $I$ intersect only in zero (here we use that the generating set was free). But $a_1a_2=a_2a_1$ is in both $\langle a_1\rangle$ and $\langle a_2\rangle$. This is possible only if $a_1a_2=0$, showing $R$ isn’t integral.

Comment: why you are assuming empty intersection? It is not part of the assumptions in my problem.

Comment: This argument could be modified for the case of commutative rings with zero divisors to show that a nonzero ideal is a free module if and only if it is a principal ideal generated by a non-zero divisor.

Comment: @Brain I did not assume empty intersection, it follows from the properties of free modules. Think about a vector space, if you take two distinct basis elements then their spans will only intersect in zero.

Comment: you are using that the generating set was free which is not an assumption I guarantee in my case.

Comment: I think the claimed statement is true because only of the second part of the problem, am I correct?

Comment: @Brain every free module has a free generating set tautologically.